# Mule getting list of objects from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mule

Need to retrieve the list of objects from S3 bucket through MULE ESB. But when getting the payload.getkey(), it's throws the error:  **unable to resolve method: org.mule.module.s3.model.ObjectListing.getKey() [arglength=0]]**

```
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="9090" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<s3:config name="Amazon_S3__Configuration" accessKey="XXXXXXX" secretKey="XXXXXXXX" doc:name="Amazon S3: Configuration"/>
<flow name="s3bucket-downloadfilesFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/getfiles" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <s3:list-objects config-ref="Amazon_S3__Configuration" bucketName="ge-datastaging-dev" prefix="Mule/inbound/" maxKeys="5" doc:name="Amazon S3"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <foreach collection="#[payload]" doc:name="For Each">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message=" inside foreach...... #[payload.getCommonPrefixes()]  ...."/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message=" ################...... #[payload.getNextMarker()]  ...."/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message=" ################...... #[payload.getKey()]  ...."/>            
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

Comment: Check 'ge-datastaging-dev' bucket have files inside folder?. Use the same way as mentioned in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956403/mule-esb-how-to-take-all-the-files-in-a-folder-inside-bucket-of-amazon-s3-get/37673489#37673489 in answer section( with 'get object content' inside foreach). It should work. Before For each In logger check for payload.

Comment: ge-datastaging-dev is a bucket name and inside bucket we have created the Mule/inbound/ folder in it. All the files are available in Mule/inbound/

Comment: Did you used 'get-object content' to retrieve key?

Comment: i am not able to retrieve the KEY:   key="#[payload.getKey()]"  It's throwing error here. If i hard-code the full path file name it's working.  but i need to take the file name dynamically.

Comment: <foreach collection="#[payload]" doc:name="For Each">
        <s3:get-object-content config-ref="Amazon_S3__Configuration" bucketName="ge-datastaging-dev" key="#[payload.getKey()]"  doc:name="Amazon S3"/>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message=" inside foreach...... #[payload.getCommonPrefixes()]  ...."/>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message=" ################...... #[payload.getNextMarker()]  ...."/>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message=" ################...... #[payload.getKey()]  ...."/>            
        </foreach>

Comment: not sure, try remove collection=#[payload] in for each and give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114018/discussion-between-star-and-integration-esb).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping on `payload`, do `<foreach>` on `ObjectSummaries` object in `ObjectListing` like this:

```
<s3:list-objects config-ref="Amazon_S3__Configuration" bucketName="ge-datastaging-dev" prefix="Mule/inbound/" maxKeys="5" doc:name="Amazon S3"/>

<foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[payload.objectSummaries]">
    <s3:get-object-content config-ref="Amazon_S3__Configuration" bucketName="#[payload.getBucketName()]" key="#[payload.getKey()]" doc:name="Amazon S3"/>

</foreach>
```